# Oracle PL/SQL OOP, get instantiated class name

Tags: oracle, oop, plsql

If I have subclass bar, which is of type foo, how can a method in foo see when it is actually being run from an instantiation of bar.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE foo AS OBJECT 
(
  mxyzptlk NUMBER, -- Because PL/SQL demands you have an attribute defined.
  MEMBER FUNCTION get_actual_class_name
    RETURN VARCHAR2
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE bar UNDER foo
(
) NOT FINAL;
/

DECLARE
  baz bar;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(baz.get_actual_class_name); -- I would hope to get 'bar' back.
END;
/
```

Is introspection at all possible in PL/SQL OOP?

Comment: The answer depends on how much you want to solve the problem, and how much you want to mess around trying to solve the problem.  Try to "Do the simplest thing that could possibly work", i.e. in foo, implement `get_actual_class_name` to return the literal 'foo' and in bar, implement `get_actual_class_name` to return the literal 'bar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to figure out the the super type because of how Oracle handles inheritance, and as @Bob Jarvis mentions you should really consider the time and performance hit getting this back will be.

As far as Oracle is concerned you are calling foo.get_actual_class_name, more information can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm#sthref1046

Using DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK we can figure out the calling procedure though and the line. From there you have a lot of parsing to get the variable name and parse for where it was declared to find the actual type.

An example of how to use FORMAT_CALL_STACK to get the calling procedure name and line number is here http://www.oracle-developer.net/content/utilities/stk.sql